# ScrolledComposite does not scroll within SashForm

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have the following SWT layout:

- TabItem

  - SashForm

    - Composite (GridLayout)

      - Label (Fill W, Grab H)
      - ScrolledComposite (Fill W/H, Grab H/V)

        - Composite (RowLayout)
    - Composite (GridLayout)

      - Label (Fill W, Grab H)
      - ScrolledComosite (Fill W/H, Grab H/V)

        - Composite (RowLayout)

The general idea is that there are two identical panes side-by-side with adjustable widths via the sash, and inside each panel is a label at the top, and a scrolled composite on the bottom. The scrolled composite will have many (1 - 50) 100x100 composites contained within the wrapped composite.

The problem is that when contained within a sash form, the scrolled composites will not scroll when the internal composite grows due to a large number of children. I do not experience this problem when I abandon the SashForm and use a regular Composite, like so:

- TabItem

  - Composite (GridLayout)

    - Label
    - ScrolledComposite

      - Composite
    - Label
    - ScrolledComposite

      - Composite

In this way, there is no extra composite container, and everything is in a grid layout. The only problem is that I can't adjust the width of the panes via a common interface (sash).

---

I have tried forcing layout using `layout()`, and setting the minimum size using `setMinSize()`. I tried swapping RowLayout with a FlowLayout (swing2swt). I am assuming this is a type of layout problem, but I do not have enough SWT experience to sort it out. The layout is perfect except for the scrolling problem.

### Source Example

All of the code was auto-generated by WindowBuilder Pro, and can be replicated by building the composite tree I specified. Here is a fragment I am using to populate the wrapped composite:

```
public void populate(Composite composite, List<Photo> items) {
   composite.setRedraw(false);
   for (Photo photo : photos) {
     PhotoComposite composite = new PhotoComposite(composite, photo, SWT.NONE);
     composite.setSize(100, 100);
   }
   composite.setRedraw(true);
   composite.layout(true);
}
```

Photo is a simple POJO, and PhotoComposite is a custom composite that takes a Photo as a parameter in the constructor in addition to the traditional Composite and style bits. This code appears to work fine according to my experiments.

Comment: Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) so people can try to improve your code?

Comment: The code is all auto-generated by WindowBuilder Pro. I wouldn't have a problem with it, but if you design the attached tree in WindowBuilder it will turn out the same. I don't have any additional code to manipulate the layout other than adding the children; I will at least attach that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was a misunderstanding of `setMinSize(int, int)`. The following changes to the populate method shown above solved the problem for me:

```
public void populate(ScrolledComposite scroll, Composite composite, List<Photo> items) {
   composite.setRedraw(false);
   for (Photo photo : photos) {
     PhotoComposite composite = new PhotoComposite(composite, photo, SWT.NONE);
     composite.setSize(100, 100);
   }
   composite.setRedraw(true);
   composite.layout(true);

   scroll.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(scroll.getSize().x, SWT.DEFAULT));
}
```

Comment: To be exact, please use `composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT)`. And BTW: that's why I wanted to see the whole relevant code...

Comment: It doesn't work with the horizontal component as `SWT.DEFAULT`, as the layout doesn't wrap anymore.